# HTML - Displaying text with <> in

Tags: html

I've run into a problem that with HTML if I want to show some text which is in between arrows, for example, `<UIKit/UIKit.h>`, it won't be displayed because it thinks it's a tag not text.

I have tried:

```
<p><UIKit/UIKit.h></p>
```

But that doesn't work either, how do you get around this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`&lt;` and `&gt;` are the HTML entities you should use in place of less than `<` and greater than `>` symbols.

Answer (score 9):

Use `&lt;` and `&gt;` in place of the arrows.

Answer (score 6):

For future reference: [W3C's HTML Document Representation](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/charset.html#h-5.3).  It describes how to encode characters, and there's a link on that page to the full list of HTML character references.